# Compare all Fields of an Object

Tags: groovy, spock

In our Integration Tests we wan't to compare every field of an Object returned by an Rest Controller with an object constructed in the test.

This example illustrates the problem:

```
class RestIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    def "Should return contracts"() {
        when:
        def actual = callRestController()

        then:
        // compare all fields of actual with "contract"
        actual == new Contract(
                number: "123",
                signDate: "2017-04-01",
                address: new Address(
                        name: "Foobar",
                        street: "Foostreet",
                        city: "Frankfurt",
                        zip: "60486"
                ),
                persons: [new Person(name: "Christian")]
        )
    }

    def callRestController() {
        return new Contract(
                number: "123",
                signDate: "2017-04-01",
                address: new Address(
                        name: "Foobar",
                        street: "Wrong Street",
                        city: "Frankfurt",
                        zip: "60486"
                ),
                persons: [new Person(name: "Frank")]
        )
    }

    static class Contract {
        String number
        String signDate
        Address address
        Person[] persons
    }

    static class Address {
        String name
        String street
        String city
        String zip
    }

    static class Person {
        String name
    }

}
```

As output we like expect something like this:

```
address.street "Wrong Street" != "Foostreet"
persons[0].name "Christian" != "Frank"
```

Breaking the assert into multiple "==" lines would lead into the correct output, but that will be not handy since some objects are quite huge.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the groovy's [@EqualsAndHashCode](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html):

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode
static class Address {
    String name
    String street
    String city
    String zip
}
```

Comment: What about nice output when objects are not equal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use unitils `assertReflectionEquals`
http://unitils.sourceforge.net/tutorial-reflectionassert.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not comprehensive but may be sufficient for your needs:

```
def compareFields( obj1, obj2, propName = null ) {
    obj1.properties.each {
        if ( it.value instanceof Object[] ) {
            def obj2Len = obj2."${it.key}".length

            it.value.eachWithIndex { collObj, idx ->
                if ( idx + 1 <= obj2Len )
                    compareFields( collObj, obj2."${it.key}"[idx], "${it.key}[${idx}]" )
            }
        }

        if ( !it.value.class.getCanonicalName().contains( 'java' ) ) {
            compareFields( it.value, obj2."${it.key}", it.key )
        }

        if ( it.value.class.getCanonicalName().contains( 'java' ) &&
                it.key != 'class' &&
                    it.value <=> obj2."${it.key}") {
            println "${propName ? "$propName." : ''}${it.key}: '${it.value}' != '" + obj2."${it.key}" + "'"
        }
    }
}
```